# Mudar src da imagem com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

Estou tentando fazer com que a imagem mude cada vez que eu clique no botão, de modo que quando eu clico na image1 ele vire image2 e quando clique nao image2 ela volte a ser image1

```
<script>
function changeImage(){
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  if(image.src = "image1.png"){
      image.src = "image2.png";
  }
  else if(image.src = "image2.png"){
      image.src = "image1.png";
  }
}
```

```
<img id="image" src="image1.png" width="490" height="364">

<button onclick="changeImage()">Mudar image</button>
```

só que ele só consegue virar image2, depois disso não volta a ser image1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que falta estudar mais um pouquinho, na comparação tem que ser no mínimo 2 iguais para teste frouxo (só testa o valor) ou 3 iguais quando quer testar tipo e valor (que é a recomendada), ***exemplo***:

```
function changeImage(){
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  if(image.src === "image1.png"){
      image.src = "image2.png";
  }
  else if(image.src === "image2.png"){
      image.src = "image1.png";
  }
}
```

ou seja o correto na comparação é:

- `image.src === "image1.png"`
- `image.src === "image2.png"`

na atribuição de valores está correto somente 1 igual.

Um outro exemplo:

```js
function changeImage(){
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  if(image.src === "https://via.placeholder.com/150/d32776"){
      image.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150/efefef";
  }
  else if(image.src === "https://via.placeholder.com/150/efefef"){
      image.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150/d32776";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/d32776" />
</div>
<button onClick="changeImage()">Mudar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo, acredito que o ponto falho no seu código é que você não está comparando quando você 1 = porque dessa forma você está atribuindo valor a variável e não comparando. Em javascript você compara com == ou também com ===

Separei um áudio que acredito que possa auxiliar mas próximas dúvidas:.

[https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_de_compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o#:~:text=O%20JavaScript%20possui%20compara%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20estritas,mesmo%20tipo%20antes%20da%20compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_de_compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o#:%7E:text=O%20JavaScript%20possui%20compara%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20estritas,mesmo%20tipo%20antes%20da%20compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Espero ter ajudado.